# android: onListItemClick doesn't fire when onItemLongClick occurred

Tags: android

In have implemented the OnItemLongClickListener. When LongClicked the list item, I enable a button of the relevant listItem. After LongClicked the button enables successfully but onListItemClick doesn't get fired. If I onListItemClick without LongClicked, it fires successfully. Why does onListItemClick doesn't fire if LongClicked fired before that?

```
    OnItemLongClickListener listener =  new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {
            Account a = null;
            a = (Account) av.getItemAtPosition(position);               
            Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "Long Clicked : " + a.getAccountName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);


  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
    Account a = null;
    a = (Account) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, a.getAccountName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: Please post your corresponding code so that we could see what the problem is

Comment: I've just posted the 2 events related to the issue.

Comment: where u setting the onItemClickListener. Is there any click event for the button too that gets visible on itemLongClick ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement like below,

**setOnItemLongClickListener**

**setOnItemClickListener**

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        Account a = null;
        a = (Account) av.getItemAtPosition(position);               
        Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "Long Clicked : " + a.getAccountName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                   

        return false;
   }
});



getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
     Account a = null;
     a = (Account) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
     Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, a.getAccountName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   };
});
```

Comment: It's just the same. onItemClick doesn't fire when once onItemLongClick is occurred.

Comment: No, it is working correctly, i tested it. lokk at the project below       https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68130108/ArrayAdapter.rar

Comment: Yes, I just checked and your sample code works fine. I think something wrong with my code and I think it's not related to these 2 events. I'll check this further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    OnItemLongClickListener listener =  new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {
            Account a = null;
            a = (Account) av.getItemAtPosition(position);               
            Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "Long Clicked : " + a.getAccountName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);
```

I just found the cause for the problem. It's the line of code I used to enable the delete button when OnItemLongClick is clicked.

**v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

When I remove that line the code works perfectly. But still I ain't got a solutions to the problem. I need to have that line of code to enable the delete button when the OnItemLongClick is clicked.

Comment: Why does the listitem or the textview of the listitem is not clickable after setting the visibility of the button to visible?

Comment: I just replaced the button with an ImageView. Then there was no issue. The two events are working smoothly. So I realized there is something wrong with the button. I think we have to set some of the properties in the button to function properly in this situation. You can simulate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the button with an ImageView. Then there was no issue. The two events are working smoothly. So I realized there is something wrong with the button. I think we have to set some of the properties in the button to function properly in this situation. You can simulate the issue.
1. User a Listview.
2. Customize the list view by adding a TextView and an ImageButton or a Button as a ListItem. Make the visibility of the button to invisible by default.
3. Implement the onItemLongClick event as above and make the button when ItemLongClicked.
4. Once you ItemLongClicked a ListItem and make the button in the ListItem Visible, onListItemClick event of the particular ListItem does not work.